# HerokuにRoute53で独自ドメインを設定する

Tags: aws, heroku

下記手順でHerokuに独自ドメインを設定したのですが、
Route53によるルーティングが正しく機能せず困っています。

1. Route53でドメイン取得

   > cocowa.works
2. Herokuにドメイン登録

   ```
   $ heroku domains:add example.com
   $ heroku domains:add www.example.com
   ```
3. Route53にホストゾーン作成
4. CNAMEレコードセット作成

   ```
   Name: www
   Type: CNAME
   Value: cocowa.herokuapp.com
   ```
5. S3バケット作成

   - バケット名

     ```
     cocowa.works
     ```
   - Static website hostingの設定

     ```
     リクエストをリダイレクトする
     　　>ターゲットバケットまたはドメイン
        www.cocowa.works
     ```
6. Aレコード作成

   ```
   Name:（空欄）
   Type: A
   Alias: Yes
   Alias Target: S3に登録した「cocowa.works」のBucketを選択
   ```

※ HerokuアプリのURL
http://cocowa.herokuapp.com/

※ 取得したドメイン
http://cocowa.works/

設定を間違えている等々あればご指摘頂けますと幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

S3 バケットは必要なのですか？
cocowa.works の Aレコードを Alias で cocowa.herokuapp.com の IPアドレスが返るようにするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとう御座います。
下記Herokuの公式チュートリアルではCNAMEを利用したルーティングが推奨されているようでして、
AレコードでIPを設定するのは非推奨とのことでした。

※ Heroku公式チュートリアル
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains


アドバイス頂き誠にありがとう御座います。

Comment: Aレコードの Alias は Route 53 の独自機能なので、一般的には CNAME でもいいのですが、「www.cocowa.works → CNAME cocowa.herokuapp.com」と同様に、「cocowa.works → CNAME cocowa.herokuapp.com」でいいのでは？
S3 Static website hosting を経由させる理由はなんですか？

Answer (score 0):

解決しました。
結果的に原因はドメインの設定側にありました。
（そもそもRoute53のルーティング設定が問題ではありませんでした...）

回答くださった皆様ありがとう御座いました。